# Add values from CheckBoxes to a specific column of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've a Form called `Patient Complaints`. I have created some complaints CheckBoxes and added a Button. Also I have added columns to the DataGridView by the name of all complaints.

What I need to do when the user checks the complaints using the CheckBoxes and then clicks a Button, the values should be inserted in specific Columns of the DataGridView.

For example, if the user checked three complaints like `Smoking`, `Chest Pain`, `Fatigue`, then these three values should be added as one row in their particular column like `Smoking` will be added to the `SmokingColumn`, `Chest Pain` will be added to the "ChestPainColumn" column and so on, as a single row.

Is there any way to do that?

I've tried this way before to add a new row to the DataGridView:

```
  this.dgViewPComplaints.Rows.Add("Value1", "Value2", "Value3");
```

but on that time I was inserting values in all columns and for now I just have to insert values in specific columns.

Comment: DataRow newRow = this.dgViewPComplaints.Rows.Add();
newRow["Smoking"] = "Value1";
newRow["Chest Pain"] = "Value2";
newRow["Fatigue"] = "Value3";

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'system.data.datarow'. This error is coming up on "this.dgViewPComplaints.Rows.Add();" this line. What is the solution for it?

Comment: If your DGV's DataSource only contains these *complaints*, you could use a `List<Complaint>` as the DGV's DataSource, where `Complaint` is a class object. You can associate its properties to the `DataPropertyName` of each Column. Use the CheckBoxes to set the corresponding class Property to true/false. When the Button is clicked, add the new `Complaint` class object to the `List<Complaint>`. Set up the GDV and the class object to whatever output you require (e.g., Yes/No, Color.Red/Color.Green etc.).

Comment: @Jimi My DataGridView does not have any data source. It is just a data grid where I am adding rows programmatically.

Comment: Yes, but the point is: do you have only the values defined by these CheckBoxes in your DGV? If yes, what I suggested is easy to setup, handle and maintain. Give it a shot.

Comment: I was using a DataTable which is a little different.  For a DGV you need following :                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            DataGridViewRow newRow = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
            newRow.Cells["Smoking"].Value = "Value1"; 
            newRow.Cells["Chest Pain"].Value = "Value2"; 
            newRow.Cells["Fatigue"].Value = "Value3";

Answer (score 0):

What about adding each CheckBox column. For example:

```
DataGGridViewCheckBoxColumn dgvCmb = new DataGGridViewCheckBoxColumn();  
dgvCmb.ValueType = typeof(bool);  
dgvCmb.Name = "Chk1";  
dgvCmb.HeaderText = "Smoking";  
dgViewPComplaints.Columns.Add(dgvCmb);
```

Comment: I've not asked for checkbox column to be added in datagridview. It is about to add values from checkboxes to datagridview's specific column.